# Upload an image in jquery mobile

Tags: php, ajax, jquery-mobile

I was required to develop a mobile application of the existing system, and I have recently learnt about Jquery Mobile, and I was fascinated that I can use php with Jquery Mobile which will make my task more simple. My recent problem is with the uploading the image from the mobile devices memory. Is it possible to upload images and store it in a BLOB field in a database table? If so is done the 'normal' php way or is there another way of doing it in Jquery Mobile.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If you want to use file uploads with jQuery Mobile you have to do two
>   things:
>
> 1) Turn off Ajax navigation using data-ajax="false" on your
>   form definition because you can't upload files using Ajax.
>
> 2)  Specify
>   the appropriate encoding type of enctype="multipart/form-data" on your
>   form.

Comment: You can't imagine how tremendously you helped me. I was on the verge of going completely insane trying to figure out why HttpPostedFileBase in the controller is always nothing when I found your answer and added data-ajax="false" and voila! You rock!

Answer (score 1):

Do just normal way of file uploading in HTML. Follow for example http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp